# How to log in by email instead of username in Spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I use Spring security. Is there a way to log in using email instead of a username in Spring security?

Comment: What exactly is your implementation? Unless there are details, no one can answer your question. Include more details like how are you getting username or emails in Spring.

Comment: in Spring security login, i implement UserDetailsService and override loadUserByUsername(String arg0) function. But i use email instead of username to login, so what should I do?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need an "email" parameter in your login form

```
<input type="email" name="email">
```

Then let your custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter know that "email" is a principal parameter now

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Finally, override loadUserByUsername() in your UserDetailsService implementation

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepo.findByEmail(email);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found!");
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This made me finally understand what usernameParameter does.

Comment: I find this not proper in Spring Framework, They should add support for authentication by email ( Explicitly ), many websites and apps use just email as identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on Tolik's answer, I found it useful to have two methods to retrieve the user with, one using the email, and the other one using username.

In the userRepository

```
Optional <User> findByEmail(String email);
Optional <User> findByUsername(String email);
```

In the Service

```
Optional <User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
if (user.isEmpty()) user = userRepository.findByUsername(email);
//if you are using non optional you just check if the user==null instead of isEmpty
```

this way you can either sign with the email or the username.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for a way to allow login by either username or email and this works exactly as I needed

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is just regard `email` as `username`.

For many cases, email contains your username. For example: `abc@gmail.com`. In this email, `abc` is your username.

So you just need to let the user input email directly.

The only thing you need to update is change your query SQL similar as below:

Change (query by username):

```
SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username=#{username}
```

to (query by email)

```
SELECT email AS username,password FROM users WHERE email=#{username}
```

Answer (score 1):

*simple way to use email*
in your AUTH

**firstly** : i create a Repository named AppUserRepository

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AppUserRepository {
    Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

**Secondaly**  i create a class named AppUserService implements UserDetailsSevice like this :

```
 private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG = "user with email %s not found";
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(
                        USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email
                        )));
    }
```

Comment: Yes but this is just terrible design on the part of Spring. They are making simple things complicated, Why should they put so much emphasis on username like this,