# How to use email as a username in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have to remove a login field from my `User` class and use `email` as a username in SecurityUtils

I've already changed `j_username` parameter in a frontend, but now the issue remains on a backend

```
public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        String userName = null;
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
                UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
            } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
                userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            }
        }
        return userName;
    }
```

and as a result `userName` is null, because`UserDetails` and `Authentication` don't have email. How could I set the field `email` as a 'j_username'? I've tried this

> [How to login by email instead of username in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673400/how-to-login-by-email-instead-of-username-in-spring-security)

solution but it's not enough since I use an `anonymousUser`

Also, I have an implementation of `UserDetailsService` but when debugging it's not called when being the `anonymousUser`

```
public class DomainUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public DomainUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
        return userFromDatabase.map(user -> {
            if (!user.getActivated()) {
                throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogin,
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the " +
            "database"));
    }
}
```

Comment: To explicitly tell your user to use their email address as their user name, just add an instruction to the sign up page in your front end. Why do you feel you need to change variable names in your backend for this?

Comment: Because it previously used login field. Now it needs to be removed and it needs to use field email instead. But when user is not authenticated this method `getCurrentUserLogin` is still getting called because the system uses `anonymousUser` and when it searches for a username it gives null in `userName`

Comment: How the field is named on the frontend has no effect how you use the field in the backend. You can still use the `j_username` field to query the database using the `email` column. Chaning the name of a field on the frontend has 0 effect on what query is being executed. You need to change your query for obtaining the user from the database, NOT the name of the field in the frontend.

Comment: I understand but the thing is idk where it is set

Comment: How do you populate [`UserDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html)? Presumably you have a [`UserDetailService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html), which is the code that decides what value is returned by `getUsername()`. Change *that* code so the "user name" is the email address.

Comment: @Andreas I have a class that implements `UserDetailsService`, I will update my question

Comment: Again it doesn't matter what your parameter is called in the front end... It could be `foobarbaz`. It is only used by Spring Security to determine which parameter to retrieve and pass onto the `UserDetailsService`. So again changing it in the frontend won't matter. What does matter is your implementation of the `UserDetailsService`. It uses a method from a repository, assuming a Spring Data JPA repository which still uses the login field. THat method shold be named `findOneByEmail`. So again don't change the frontend, change the backend.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my question, there is an implementation of `UserDetailsService`. So I should just change `findOneByLogin` to `findOneByEmail` in `loadUserByUsername`? Probably worth mentioning that I'm using default anonymousUser authentication. I've tried to change to `findOneByEmail` but debug says that it doesn't go to `loadUserByUsername`, at least with anonymous authentication. I'm using mongodb, what are my options?

Comment: THe fact that you have anonymous authentication means that stuff gets bypassed. So instead of JPA yu are using MongoDB with Spring Data Mongo? Again don't mess with the front-end/incoming request, just change your userdetailsservice implementation. That and only that is the change you need to make.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I understand, the frontend works fine, not messing with it. I'm using Spring Data Mongo. So yeah, this is my question, how do I have to change userdetailsservice implementation? I changed to find by email but again it gives login field. I believe there is a way to configure getPrincipal to return email field somehow..

Comment: @M.Deinum  `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {` here the field login contains login. I don't believe that changing the name of it to email will cause any affect since it's called somewhere else(couldn't find it in the project) and is not called when anonymousUser

Comment: Again the ONLY change you need to do is to change your repositories query method... Spring Security will do everything else. It doesn't matter how the parameter is named, it doesn't matter how the name of method argument is called. What matters is how it is handled in your custom `UserDetailsService`. Spring Security will get the parameter from the request and pass it to the `UserDetailsService` nothing more, nothing less. Regarding the rename to `findOneByEmail` I assume your entity has an email field else it won't work and if you use an dedicated query you need to change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192424/discussion-between-kyrylo-lukeniuk-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal you will have to control anonymous user behavior. I had that issue before and when the user is logged in the queries are working fine. As M. Denim suggested you should search by email here -> `Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneByEmail(lowercaseLogin);`

But in case of anonymous user in `getCurrentUserLogin()` you have to write an if statement to return `anonymous@localhost` in case the `userName = anonymousUser`

Answer (score 0):

here i share some code from  my Spring Security Configuration class

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login")
.usernameParameter("logInId").passwordParameter("password")
```

here i use 'logInId' parameter for login instead of default parameter....

i think you searching some thing like this .......

Comment: I've set that already, but it doesn't affect `Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();`. It still looks for username login

Comment: This only changes the name of the parameter coming from the front-end to be used as the username/userid to login with.